# Statement always true

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a script where if there is a second argument the script will run else it will run an else statement but even if there is no second argument it will always run the script

```
if(member && args.slice(1) !== undefined)
  {
    member.kick(args.slice(1).join(' ')).then(() =>{
        message.channel.send("Successfully kicked " + "`" + user.tag + "`" +" for " + "**" +args.slice(1).join(' ') + "**" + " ")
    }).catch(err =>{
        channel.message.send("An unexpected error occured. Logs were sent to the devs")
        console.log(err);
        return;
    });
  }else{
    if(member){
        member.kick().then(() =>{
            message.channel.send("Successfullys kicked " + "`" + user.tag + "`")
            console.log (args[2], args)
        }).catch(err =>{
            channel.message.send("An unexpected error occured. Logs were sent to the devs")
            console.log(err);
            return;
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly is your problem. What are you trying to accomplish, and what problems are you encountering? Can you provide more information or maybe examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `args` is an array, `.slice()` will always return an array and never `undefined`. You should check for the length directly:

```
if (member) {
  const kick = args.length > 1 ? member.kick(args.slice(1).join(' ')) : member.kick(); 
  kick.then(() =>{
    message.channel.send("Successfully kicked " + "`" + user.tag + "`" +" for " + "**" +args.slice(1).join(' ') + "**" + " ")
  }).catch(err =>{
    channel.message.send("An unexpected error occured. Logs were sent to the devs")
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`args.slice(1)` will never be `undefined`. If the array `args` is too short, its result will be the empty array `[]`. This is different from `undefined`.